# UWP CommandBar dynamic overflow behavior not working

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, commandbar

On [this page in Windows Dev Center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/app-bars) it says

> The new dynamic overflow behavior will automatically move primary commands into the SecondaryCommands area when space is limited.

But in my App there are only 4 Buttons Visible, the 5th one is not there, also not if I open the Menu, I have to put it manually into the `SecondaryCommands` List, to make Windows showing it.

 I made a plain simple CommandBar to test it

```
<CommandBar>
    <AppBarButton Icon="Find" Label="test" />
    <AppBarButton Icon="Find" Label="test" />
    <AppBarButton Icon="Find" Label="test" />
    <AppBarButton Icon="Find" Label="test" />
    <AppBarButton Icon="Find" Label="test" />
</CommandBar>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Build Target and Min Version is 10.0 10586.

 Also I noticed that `CommandBarOverflowButtonVisibility` and similar properties can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature that won't appear until the Anniversary Update--the documentation has just been updated too early. You can see the feature get explained in detail in [this video from //BUILD 2016](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/B853) at about 11:35. It is *not* currently available in Build 10586.